# Как загрузить гиф картинку в профиль?

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника, аватар-пользователя

Сегодня увидел у одного  [**участника**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/285292/lets-say-pie)  в профиле Gif картинку и удивился. До этого я думал, что такое невозможно.

Хотел загрузить для себя, не получилось. Вроде загрузился, потом обновил страницу и увидел что результат не обновился.

Подскажите, как загрузить гифку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раньше это было возможно из-за проблемы, описанной [здесь](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/260198). Если в период, когда был этот баг, пользователь загружал gif'ку, то она отображалась в профиле и анимировалась. Сейчас (и в период до этого бага) отображается только первый фрейм.

Так что, ответ: на данный момент никак, ждите повторения бага (:

Comment: Жалко =( а так хотелось .